# I'm not entirely sure the Big O complexity of this

Tags: c++

This will find the nth element in an unsorted array as if it was sorted, and I want it to run below n log n time, but I'm not entirely sure the run time of this, would it be O(n^2)?

```
int nthElement(std::vector<int> vec, int n)
{
  n--;
  int smallest = vec[0];
  int index = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
  {
    if (vec[i] < smallest)
    {
      smallest = vec[i];
      index = i;
    }
  }
  vec.erase(vec.begin() + index);
  if( n == 0)
  {
    std::cout << "Do I get here?" << std::endl;
    return smallest;
  } 
  return nthElement(vec, n);
}
```

Comment: why don't you want to use `std::nth_element`?

Comment: I'm just trying to do this for a self teach type thing.

Comment: Yes, O(n^2). One n for the for loop and one n for the tail recusion.

Comment: This complexity is `O(n x size)`

Comment: @Damien `O(n x size)`, size being a constant, would reduce to simply `O(n)`

Comment: @davedwards `size` (the vector size) is greater than `n`.

Comment: So it would not be o(n^2) as stated above?

Comment: Let us assume n=2 and size=10000... It is O(n^2) if we assume that n can take any value lower than size. Generally, we estimate the complexity relatively to the size of the problem, and generally we call `n`  or `N` this size.... The ambiguity comes from that. Complexity is O(size^2), O(N^2) if we call `N` this size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself what's `n` compared to `vec.size()`. Assuming `n` is kind of random between `0` and `vec.size()-1`, the following holds true:
- in the best case, `n = 0`.
- in the worst case, `n = vec.size()`.
- in the average case, `n ~ vec.size()` (`~` means proportional).

So the time complexity, in general, is indeed `O(n^2) = O(vec.size()^2) = O(n*vec.size())`.